# Why must I invoke mknod externally instead of directly in my driver?

Tags: linux, drivers, devices

Reading through all the books/articles/tutorials/examples on character device drivers I could find, they all cover how to acquire a major number in my driver code and all suggest that I do so dynamically by invoking `alloc_chrdev_region()`.  To make the actual device node, they all then tell me to invoke `mknod`  outside my driver code either manually or in a script.  One reference wants my driver to print the major number. Another wants me to use `awk` on `/proc/devices` to find the major number. There is mention of the function `mknod()`, but it appears to be intended for use in userland code.

I'm obviously missing something since I don't understand why there isn't a way for my driver to be self contained, i.e, I do `modprobe my_driver` and end up with, say, `/dev/my_driver` created without having to do anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The command pair device_create and class_create do the trick in Linux. Check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970595/create-a-device-node-in-code

Comment: This appears to be a most interesting approach.  I intend to pursue it -- once management puts me back on the project that prompted my question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unix has traditionally followed the "mechanism, not policy" tradition. In the case of device drivers, this means the driver identity in the kernel is just the major/minor device number. Naming the device (the "policy*) using mknod has been left to user space.

Comment: A lot of the references I looked at do emphasize the "mechanism, not policy" philosophy.  However the /dev directory is full of entries that don't seem to have gotten there via any external scripting that I've been able to find.  For example, `/dev/ttyACM0` is the device created by the USB CDC/ACM (USB "serial port") driver though I've not yet figured out how it does it.  I want my driver to be just like that.

Comment: The `udev` device manager manages the entries in `/dev`. See the [Wikipedia article on udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev)

Comment: The challenge of Linux is that well written comprehensive documentation is invariably out-of-date while the most up-to-date techniques are poorly documented.  Combine that with the mix of old and new techniques that exist in the code base confounded with the difficulty of telling which is which -- well thanks to the gods of coffee and programming that StackExchange exists!  The pointer to udev was most useful.